# WebRTC iceConnectionState failed when using react-native Android

Tags: webrtc, react-native

Both clients connect to the signalling server on the first phone and exchange the offer, answer and ICE candidates, but then the iceConnectionState goes from checking to failed and the streams don't get exchanged.